# Two possessive pronouns (hers, yours) in a sentence

Tags: ellipsis, possessives, reflexive-pronouns, parallelism

> You both have good cars. But **hers** is better than **yours**.

Can I say that? I know that I can say "But **her car** is better than **yours**." Would it be too much to use two possessive pronouns in a sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  You can use multiple pronouns as long as they don't create ambiguity.  In this case, there should be no ambiguity as **yours** must refer to the listener, while **hers** must refer to a third (female) party.

Even a sentence like the following is grammatical:

> They both have good cars, but **his** is better than **his**.

To make this sentence unambiguous, though, you would have to point or gesture toward the people you're referring to as you say the pronouns aloud.

Really, it's just a matter of making sure you're communicating clearly.

Comment: Worth noting: generally in English, to avoid ambiguity and confusion, do not use two pronouns of the same gender (possessive or not) in the same phrase. A pronoun should reference the last explicitly named proper noun of that gender. For example: Sally went to the store. She needs new shoes. "She" clearly references "Sally". But if you said "Sally went to the store. Mary went with her, because she  needs new shoes." "She" refers to Mary; if you intended "Sally" this sentence would be confusing. Context can also be clarifying in crossed pronoun situations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't find any problem in using two possessive pronouns in a sentence. In fact, you can also include *mine* that will still make sense!

> We all have cars, but *mine* is better than *hers* and *yours*.

I found several instances on authentic sites. This included a book as well which read...

> *“Who can say that yours are better than hers, or that hers is better than yours? They are as individual as we are. Both are good."* - From **On the Road Home** By *Eunice Long.*